# What controls indentation of lines following an open square bracket when using cindent?

Tags: indentation, filetype, options

I am trying to build my own indent file for JavaScript.  The default indent file for JavaScript turns cindent on, with minimal modifications, and I am using that as a base.

On Vim 7.3 for OSX El Capitan, typing an array produces the following by default:

```
var test = [
1,
    2,
    3
    ];
```

And note, while not legal JavaScript, I noticed not using a comma produces a slightly different behavior:

```
var test = [
1
2
3
];
```

On 7.4, typing the above two examples produces what I expect:

```
var test = [
    1,
    2,
    3
];

var test = [
    1
    2
    3
];
```

However, if you include some characters immediately following the open square bracket it goes back out of whack:

```
var test = [1
2,
    3,
    4
];
```

What controls the indentation of the lines between square brackets as well as the placement of the closing square bracket?  When viewing the [Vim documentation](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/indent.html), I don't see a cinoptions value that captures this.

Comment: Have you tried this one https://github.com/pangloss/vim-javascript ?

Comment: I have but that plugin appears to indent everything from scratch using custom VimScript functions instead of built in rules.

Answer (score 1):

Judging from your comment above, you want to use only `cinoptions` to control the indent for square brackets.  It simply wasn't possible before 7.4.355 from what I see in the [source code](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/dc633cf82758f67f656cda7fa8ccc30414ee53f8/src/misc1.c#L8484).  Click blame up top to see the tagged version, but it's going take a while to load.

Since it looks like `cinoptions` was originally for C, C++, and Java, it only dealt with curly braces and parenthesis because square brackets are used for defining array sizes or accessing indexes in those languages－not initializing them.

> What controls the indentation of the lines between square brackets as well as the placement of the closing square bracket?

After 7.4.355, it's the `J` option that controls the indentation, but nothing specifically for square brackets.  From what I glossed over in the source, the `J` option only signifies that JavaScript syntax should be considered (`curbuf->b_ind_js`).  It looks for a previous line that's terminated by a comma or opening bracket to line up with.  In your fourth example, the line ends with a `1`, so it doesn't increase the indentation.

If the first line in your fourth example ended with a `[` or `,` (or both `[,`) the subsequent lines would increase the indent.